# How to disable Gecko package popup for Wine?

Tags: linux, wine, command-line-arguments, popups, dependencies

When I run my app under Wine:

```
wine my_app.exe
```

I've got this annoying popup:

[image: Wine could not find a Gecko package]

which says:

> Wine could not find a Gecko package which is needed for applications embedding HTML to work correctly.

I understand that I need to install [Gecko](http://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) (either by `sudo apt-get install wine-gecko\*` or using the [install-addons.sh](http://web.archive.org/web/20160506085513/http://winezeug.googlecode.com:80/svn/trunk/install-addons.sh) script),

however **I don't want to install Gecko**, but simply suppress/hide this message as my app works correctly when pressing *Cancel* button.

How I can do that? Is there any parameter for that?

Running `wine --help` or `man wine` doesn't say much.

Comment: Did you build the app yourself? I suspect the build has an external library reference, even though you may not call the functions in it. You could try rebuilding with static libraries, thereby eliminating external calls. For what it's worth, I don't have `Gecko` installed, and even Firefox 39.0 runs quite happily without it under Wine 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 15.04 without errors. Firefox has a `dependentlibs.list` file in its installation directory: I presume these DLLs are loaded dynamically on start-up: perhaps you could use a similar technique.

Comment: The wine is installed from the binaries (`sudo apt-get install wine winetricks` => `wine1.6`) on [Ubuntu vivid VM](https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/vivid64). And the [app](https://download.mql5.com/cdn/web/metaquotes.software.corp/mt4/mt4setup.exe) is a standard installer, so there is nothing much to rebuild.

Comment: That EXE calls WINHTTP.DLL, which may well be the culprit. I can only guess why it might be there: maybe there is licence checking during the installation, and if you do not do this then you will not see a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be disabled by exporting the following options:

```
export WINEDLLOVERRIDES="mscoree,mshtml="
```

Related:

- [3.5. Environment variables](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/x275)
- [Disable Mono installing dialogue.](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=16320)
- [Running Wine without downloading Mono and Gecko packages.](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23560)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't worry about Gecko being too much to install, and Wine may need it someday for something to work.
There is a simple fix to this (and perhaps other problems caused by changing versions)... Delete the files: `system.reg`, `user.reg`, `userdef.reg`, and `.update-timestamp` which are in your `.wine` folder.  Then reinstall Wine... the easy way is through the synaptic package manager in Linux Mint.  Wine will require installing Gecko once again, but this should be only other time...