# wineboot hangs and does not complete

Tags: macos, wine

I'm having a strange issue with Wine on macOS 10.13.4. I have Homebrew installed and have installed Wine with `brew install wine winetricks`.

```
$ wine --version
wine-3.0
```

When I run `wineboot --init > log 2>&1` I get a dialog box that says `The Wine configuration in /Users/richard/.wine is being updated, please wait`. The log file looks like this:

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/Users/richard/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0017:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0017:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
0017:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
001b:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
001b:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
001b:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
0010:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0010:fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x6dbd1518
0010:fixme:winsock:set_dont_fragment IP_DONTFRAGMENT for IPv4 not supported in this platform
001d:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x69ebd3de, context 0x9e6640, init_notify 0, handle 0x12dfa40): stub
0009:err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out
004a:fixme:mountmgr:DriverEntry failed to create device error c0000035
004a:err:winedevice:async_create_driver failed to create driver L"MountMgr": c0000035
005a:err:hid_report:process_hid_report Device reports coming in too fast, last report not read yet!
005a:err:hid_report:process_hid_report Device reports coming in too fast, last report not read yet!
    [THE ABOVE LINE IS REPEATED 1000s OF TIMES]
```

When I killed `wine64` with a SIGTERM after an hour, the following lines were appended to the log file:

```
006e:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
006e:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
006e:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
006c:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
006c:fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x6d5d3018
0070:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x6a0cb608, context 0x958950, init_notify 0, handle 0x119fce8): stub
006c:fixme:winsock:set_dont_fragment IP_DONTFRAGMENT for IPv4 not supported in this platform
wine: configuration in '/Users/richard/.wine' has been updated.
```

- I did `rm -rf ~/.wine` before all this
- `WINEPREFIX` is unset
- Homebrew and `wine` are at the latest available version
- `wineboot`, `wineboot --init` and `wineboot --update` all have the same problem

How can I get `wineboot` to complete without hanging?

Edit: I'm currently setting up a macOS 10.13.4 virtual machine to test if the same thing happens in there.

Edit 2: I've tested in a fresh macOS 10.13.4 virtual machine and I'm having the same problem. I've tried `brew install wine` (for Wine 3.0 stable) and `brew install wine --HEAD` (for the latest Wine 3.7), both have the same problem with `wineboot` hanging.

Edit 3: I think the log line `0009:err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out` might be the problem, no idea how to get around it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that this is a known bug with the version from Homebrew, see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26384. Workaround for now is to use the official version from https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html.

Answer (score 3):

The `wineboot` command hangs, because it most likely gives you some error popup. To see the popup message error, make sure you've proper `DISPLAY` variable configured which points to your current display.

The common issue is popup about missing Gecko. The workaround to run `wineboot` non-interactively, is to [ignore the Gecko package](https://superuser.com/q/948508/87805) by the following command:

```
WINEDLLOVERRIDES="mscoree,mshtml=" wineboot -i
```

Another issue could be related to .NET/rundll32, see: [bug #47144](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47144).

Comment: [Bug #41727](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41727) actually discusses the issue.